# iOS - can't get background to act as tappable object

Tags: ios, keyboard, touch

I am struggling to get the background to act as a tappable object in a small iOS app I'm developing.
I have 4 input text fields, and if I tap on the background when in the first one, the keyboard goes away.
However, that does not happen with the other 3 and I can't see why.
I made a Touch Down connection with the View controller.
Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you share your code for the method that's supposed to resign the keyboard?

Comment: Are you resigning first responder on all of your text fields, or just the first one?

Comment: Also, are you setting all of the textfield's delegates to self? Some code would be nice.

Comment: You need to post the code of your UITextFieldDelegate method implementations & the code of the method that dismisses the keyboard.